# exception throw :'data parameter is nil', error occured when accessing HTTP web services in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm New to iPhone application development, I'm facing the following Error rarely when making API Calls. Most of the time I'm getting the correct response from the server server. But Sometimes I'm facing the following error. I have checked there is no fault with the URL.
Thanks in advance., Can anyone please share your knowledge to access API call without this Bug.

Here is my code

```
-(void)callUserAPI {

    arrList = nil;

    NSString *targetUrl;

    //    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    //        targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@index.php/restapi/chats?limit=%@",[dict valueForKey:@"support_location"],@"1000"];
    //    else
    targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“https://yoururl”,[dict valueForKey:@"support_location"],@"1000"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [dict valueForKey:@"username"], [dict valueForKey:@"password"]];

    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];

    [request addValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSLog(@"%@",request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
      ^(NSData * _Nullable data,

        NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,

        NSError * _Nullable error) {


             NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

             self->arrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             self->arrPending = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             self->arrActive = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             self->arrClosed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             self->arrList =[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"list"];

             // 0 - pending, 1 - active, 2 - closed chat,

             for (NSDictionary *temp in self->arrList) {


                 if ([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 1 ) {
                     if (!([[self->dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue] == 1) ) {
                         if ([[temp valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue] == [[self->dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue]) {
                             [self->arrActive addObject:temp];
                         }
                     }else{
                         [self->arrActive addObject:temp];
                     }
                 }
                 else if ([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 2 ) {
                     if (!([[self->dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue] == 1) ) {
                         if ([[temp valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue] == [[self->dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] intValue]) {
                             [self->arrClosed addObject:temp];
                         }
                     }else{
                         [self->arrClosed addObject:temp];
                     }
                 }else if ([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 0 ) {

                     [self->arrPending addObject:temp];

                 }




                 //            if ([dict valueForKey:@"user_id"] == [temp valueForKey:@"user_id"]) {
                 //                if ([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 0) {
                 //                    [self->arrPending addObject:temp];
                 //                }else if([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 1) {
                 //                    [self->arrActive addObject:temp];
                 //                }else if([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 2) {
                 //                    [self->arrClosed addObject:temp];
                 //                }else{
                 //
                 //                }
                 //            }


             }


             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                 self->_lblActiveCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)self->arrActive.count];
                 self->_lblPendingCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)self->arrPending.count];
                 self->_lblClosedCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)self->arrClosed.count];

                 [self->_tblView reloadData];

                 [self->HUD hide:YES];
             });


      }] resume];
}
```

This is what i get whenever my app comes in background to foreground.

> 2019-06-19 16:53:56.366971+0530 LiveTracker[523:62321] TIC TCP Conn
>   Failed [122:0x282b77540]: 1:53 Err(53) 2019-06-19 16:53:56.367912+0530
>   LiveTracker[523:62321] Task
>   .<122> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: 53 [1:53]) 2019-06-19 16:53:56.374704+0530
>   LiveTracker[523:62264] Task
>   .<122> finished with error -
>   code: 53 2019-06-19 16:53:56.378241+0530 LiveTracker[523:62305] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1b76ac518 0x1b68879f8 0x1b75b6c70 0x1b8046390 0x100c7b65c 0x1b7c80688 0x1b7c94220 0x1b8110f68
>   0x1b801d420 0x1b801c908 0x1b8112cec 0x10141f6f0 0x101420c74
>   0x101423ffc 0x101423458 0x101431dc8 0x1014327ac 0x1b72cd1b4
>   0x1b72cfcd4) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely generated by:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

This is because sometime the web requests fails, either due to timeout, bad connection or even simply an expired web session.  Regardless of the cause of the error, you HAVE to check whether the API request succeeded or failed before assuming that you have data to parse.

At a minimum check if `data` is nil in your callback handler.